# FindRoot::trcx when using NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, numerics, complex

```
Clear[M, R, Pr, Ec, H, Rd, γ1, γ2, Δ1, Δ, λ1, λ0, Nb, Nt, t, Le, K1, 
  L, δ, ξ, ϵ, u, v, θ, Θ, ϕ, Φ, y];
M = 2;
R = 2;
Pr = 21;
Ec = 1;
H = 3;
Rd = 2;
γ1 = 1;
γ2 = 1;
Δ1 = 1;
Δ = 0.1;
λ0 = 3;
λ1 = 2;
Nb = 0.2;
Nt = 0.3;
t = Pi/3;
Le = 0.2;
K1 = 0.001;
L = 0.01;
δ = 0.3;
ξ = 0.3;
ϵ = 0.1;
Equ1 = (1 + 6 Δ1 u'[y]^2) u''[y] - R u'[y] - 
    M^2 u[y] + λ0 == 0;
Equ2 = (1 + I γ1 + 6 Δ1 u'[y]^2) v''[y] - 
    R v'[y] + 12 Δ1 u'[y] u''[y] v'[y] - (M^2 + I H^2) v[
      y] + λ1 == 0;
Equ3 = ((1 + (4 Rd/3)) (1/Pr) - (Δ R^2)/H^2) θ''[
      y] - R θ'[y] + Nt (θ'[y])^2 + Nb ϕ'[y] θ'[y] + 2 Ec Δ1 (u'[y])^4 + 
    Ec (u'[y])^2 + Ec (M u[y])^2 == 0;
Equ4 = ((1 + (4 Rd/3)) (1/Pr) - (Δ R^2)/
        H^2) Θ''[y] - (1 + 2 I Δ) R Θ'[y] + 
    2 Nt Θ'[y] θ'[y] + Nb (Θ'[y] ϕ'[y] + θ'[y] Φ'[
         y]) + (Δ - I) H^2 Θ[y] + 8 Ec Δ1 (u'[y]^3) v'[y] + 2 Ec u'[y] v'[y] + 
    2 Ec M^2 u[y] v[y] == 0;
Equ5 = ϕ''[y] - R Pr Le ϕ'[y] + (Nt/Nb) θ''[
      y] - γ1 Pr Le ϕ[y] - K1 Pr Le == 0;
Equ6 = Φ''[y] - R Pr Le Φ'[y] + (Nt/Nb) Θ''[
      y] - (γ1 + I H^2) Pr Le Φ[y] == 0;
Bcs = {u[0] == 0, v[0] == 0, θ[0] == 0, Θ[0] == 0, ϕ[0] == 
    0, Φ[0] == 0, u[1] == 0, v[1] == 0, θ[1] == 1, Θ[1] == 0, ϕ[1] == 
    1, Φ[1] == 0};

solu = NDSolve[{Equ1, Equ2, Equ3, Equ4, Equ5, Equ6, Bcs}, {u, 
    v, θ, Θ, ϕ, Φ}, {y, 0, 1}];
```

When I run the above code, I got the following error:

> FindRoot::trcx "The search has encountered a complex value and the trust region step control method is only implemented for real values".

Why does this happen and how can I solve my equations?

Comment: Try a quick experiment. Replace all constants that have a decimal point with rationals that do not have a decimal point. Then append `WorkingPrecision->64` to the end of your `NDSolve` and see what happens. It will be slower because it isn't using faster less precise machine floating point, but will it complete without your error? Hopefully it will solve your problem.

Comment: I have tried both of them but could not get the solution. But some of the collegues solved these kind of problems in mathematica. I don't know how. They don't help me

Comment: `Equ1` and `Equ2` only have `u` and `v`. Could `DSolve` or `NDSolve` find those which would leave fewer unknown equations to solve. You may need more boundary conditons.

Answer (score 3):

We can solve this problem step by step as @Bill recommended as follows

```
Clear[M, R, Pr, Ec, H, 
  Rd, \[Gamma]1, \[Gamma]2, \[CapitalDelta]1, \[CapitalDelta], \
\[Lambda]1, \[Lambda]0, Nb, Nt, t, Le, K1, 
  L, \[Delta], \[Xi], \[Epsilon], u, 
  v, \[Theta], \[CapitalTheta], \[Phi], \[CapitalPhi], y];
M = 2;
R = 2;
Pr = 21;
Ec = 1;
H = 3;
Rd = 2;
\[Gamma]1 = 1;
\[Gamma]2 = 1;
\[CapitalDelta]1 = 1;
\[CapitalDelta] = 0.1;
\[Lambda]0 = 3;
\[Lambda]1 = 2;
Nb = 0.2;
Nt = 0.3;
t = Pi/3;
Le = 0.2;
K1 = 0.001;
L = 0.01;
\[Delta] = 0.3;
\[Xi] = 0.3;
\[Epsilon] = 0.1;
Equ1 = (1 + 6 \[CapitalDelta]1 u'[y]^2) u''[y] - R u'[y] - 
    M^2 u[y] + \[Lambda]0 == 0;
Equ2 = (1 + I \[Gamma]1 + 6 \[CapitalDelta]1 u'[y]^2) v''[y] - 
    R v'[y] + 
    12 \[CapitalDelta]1 u'[y] u''[y] v'[y] - (M^2 + I H^2) v[
      y] + \[Lambda]1 == 0;
Equ3 = ((1 + (4 Rd/3)) (1/Pr) - (\[CapitalDelta] R^2)/H^2) \[Theta]''[
      y] - R \[Theta]'[y] + Nt (\[Theta]'[y])^2 + 
    Nb \[Phi]'[y] \[Theta]'[y] + 2 Ec \[CapitalDelta]1 (u'[y])^4 + 
    Ec (u'[y])^2 + Ec (M u[y])^2 == 0;
Equ4 = ((1 + (4 Rd/3)) (1/Pr) - (\[CapitalDelta] R^2)/
        H^2) \[CapitalTheta]''[
      y] - (1 + 2 I \[CapitalDelta]) R \[CapitalTheta]'[y] + 
    2 Nt \[CapitalTheta]'[y] \[Theta]'[y] + 
    Nb (\[CapitalTheta]'[y] \[Phi]'[y] + \[Theta]'[y] \[CapitalPhi]'[
         y]) + (\[CapitalDelta] - I) H^2 \[CapitalTheta][y] + 
    8 Ec \[CapitalDelta]1 (u'[y]^3) v'[y] + 2 Ec u'[y] v'[y] + 
    2 Ec M^2 u[y] v[y] == 0;
Equ5 = \[Phi]''[y] - 
    R Pr Le \[Phi]'[y] + (Nt/Nb) \[Theta]''[
      y] - \[Gamma]1 Pr Le \[Phi][y] - K1 Pr Le == 0;
Equ6 = \[CapitalPhi]''[y] - 
    R Pr Le \[CapitalPhi]'[y] + (Nt/Nb) \[CapitalTheta]''[
      y] - (\[Gamma]1 + I H^2) Pr Le \[CapitalPhi][y] == 0;
Bcs = {u[0] == 0, 
   v[0] == 0, \[Theta][0] == 0, \[CapitalTheta][0] == 0, \[Phi][0] == 
    0, \[CapitalPhi][0] == 0, u[1] == 0, 
   v[1] == 0, \[Theta][1] == 1, \[CapitalTheta][1] == 0, \[Phi][1] == 
    1, \[CapitalPhi][1] == 0};
```

First step

```
U = NDSolveValue[{Equ1, u[0] == 0, u[1] == 0}, u, {y, 0, 1}]
```

Visualization

```
Plot[U[y], {y, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> {"y", "u"}]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Second step

```
V = NDSolveValue[{Equ2 /. u -> U, v[0] == 0, v[1] == 0}, v, {y, 0, 1}]
```

Visualization

```
ReImPlot[V[y], {y, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> {"y", "v"}]
```

[image: Figure 2]

Third step

```
sol35 = 
 ParametricNDSolve[{Equ3 /. u -> U, 
   Equ5, \[Theta][1] == 1, \[Theta]'[1] == t1, \[Phi][1] == 
    1, \[Phi]'[1] == p1}, {\[Theta], \[Phi]}, {y, 0, 1}, {t1, p1}];
sol0 = 
 NMinimize[(\[Theta][t1, p1][0]^2 + \[Phi][t1, p1][0]^2) /. 
   sol35, {t1, p1}, Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"]

(*Out[]= {1.05342*10^-16, {t1 -> 3.73777, p1 -> 4.10266}}*)
```

Visualization

```
T[y_] := 
 Evaluate[{\[Theta][t1, p1][y], \[Phi][t1, p1][y]} /. sol35 /. 
   sol0[[2]]];



P[y_] := Evaluate[\[Phi][t1, p1][y] /. sol35 /. sol0[[2]]];

Plot[{T[y], P[y]}, {y, 0, 1}, PlotLegends -> {\[Theta], \[Phi]}, 
 Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> Automatic]
```

[image: Figure 3]

Last step

```
sol46 = NDSolve[{Equ4, 
    Equ6, \[CapitalTheta][0] == 0, \[CapitalPhi][0] == 
     0, \[CapitalTheta][1] == 0, \[CapitalPhi][1] == 0} /. {u -> U, 
    v -> V, \[Theta] -> T, \[Phi] -> 
     P}, {\[CapitalTheta], \[CapitalPhi]}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

Visualization

```
ReImPlot[
 Evaluate[{\[CapitalTheta][y], \[CapitalPhi][y]} /. sol46[[1]]], {y, 
  0, 1}, PlotLegends -> {\[CapitalTheta], \[CapitalPhi]}, 
 Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> Automatic]
```

[image: Figure 4]